# Reload main page after data changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app that, when it is starting, loads a bunch of files from a directory in the underlying OS, after this it presents a page (generated with PUG, if it makes any difference) that shows the the list of loaded files to the user and if one is clicked it shows the contents. One of the buttons on the page allows the user to create a new file (by spawning a system command based on the user's input).

My question is how do I reload the main page after the new file is created so that the web page now shows the new file that was added. In the future there will be a feature to delete a file as well, so I will also need to reload after this to show that the file has been deleted.

TIA for any assistance.

Code is short enough that I can include it here (please let me know if I am doing this the long difficult way, I am jut learning)

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// Read profile names
const profileFolder = '/home/pi/configs/';
const fs = require('fs');
var profiles = [];

function init() {
   profiles = fs.readdirSync(profileFolder);
   for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
      try {
         profile = fs.readFileSync(profileFolder + profiles[i], 'utf8');
         profiles[i] = {
            pname: profiles[i].split('.')[0],
            profile: profile
         };
      }
      catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
      }
   };
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   init();
   res.render(__dirname + '/views/index.pug', {vpnprofiles: profiles});
});

app.get('/addnew', function(req, res) {
   let pname = req.query.newprofile;
   console.log(`Adding new profile: ${pname}`);
   exec("pivpn -a -n "+pname, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
         console.log(`ERROR: ${error.message}`);
         return;
      }
      if (stderr) {
         console.log(`STDERR: ${stderr}`);
         return;
      }
      console.log(`${stdout}`);
      res.send("Done!");
   });
   return;
});

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Server started on port ${port}!`)
});
```

/public/script.js

```
function genQRcode(p, n) {
  const nl = '\n';
  const rep = '<br>'
  document.getElementById("qrcode").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("profile").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Profile Details (" + n + ")";
  new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), p);
  document.getElementById("profile").style.padding = "10px";
  document.getElementById("profile").innerHTML = p.replaceAll(nl, rep);
}

// Create a new profile
function addn(pn) {
  console.log(pn);
  var newname = prompt("Enter profile name:", "");
  if ((newname != null) && (newname != "")) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < pn.length; i++) {
      if (pn[i]['pname'] == newname) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      fetch(`/addnew?newprofile=${newname}`).then((messages) => {console.log("messages");});
    }
    else { alert("profile already exists"); }
  }
  window.location = "http://192.168.1.3:8000/";
  window.location.reload(true);
  //return failse;
}
```

and finally the pug file

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title PiVPN Profiles
    script !{addnew}
    script(src='../scripts/qrcode.js')
    script(src='../scripts/script.js')
    link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="../styles/style.css")
  body
    .grid
      .box.nav
        a(href='/') Home
        .btn(onclick=`addn(${JSON.stringify(vpnprofiles)});`) New Profile
      .box.sidebar
        h2 Profiles
        ul
          each prof in vpnprofiles
            li(onclick=`genQRcode(${JSON.stringify(prof.profile)},${JSON.stringify(prof.pname)})`)=prof.pname
      .box.content
        h1#title Profile Details
        p.qrcode#qrcode
        p.profile#profile
      .box.footer
        p.small Version: 0.1a
```

Comment: Are you looking for `location.reload()`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have I tried? humm... location.reload() location.reload(true) location.replace("MyURLhere")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am reading this wrong, but can you make use of `window.location = 'yourpage'` (a client-side JS solution) or similar page refresh techniques?